# How can I disable selection highlight auto-copying?

Tags: x11, xfce, clipboard

I've finally found myself at home in Linux, but there is still one thing that has bothered me since the start, and I have not found a realistic solution:

**How do I disable the automatic copying of highlighted text in Linux's desktop environment** 
My Desktop Environment is XFCE, Window Manager is Openbox and it's all held together by Archlinux, I do however have these issues in other distributions.

Every time I go to replace a section of text I:

Highlight the source then press the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>
I then select the text I want to replace and since highlighting text automatically copies it to the clipboard, manually reselect from clipman the selection I just copied, and paste it that way. This is very inefficient. 
I have resorted, out of desperation to using Windows for heavy editing of Source / Documents.

I would prefer to have copy paste routine identical to that which Windows uses
Select-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>Select-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>.

**edit**

The problem was *my fault all along*!

 I had ignorantly pasted `autocutsel -selection PRIMARY -fork &` into my `.xprofile`, causing autocutsel to sync all my selections into the PRIMARY clipboard.
[For more info](http://mutelight.org/subtleties-of-the-x-clipboard)

Comment: Nit: Ctrl-C is _not_ the usual, that's Windows talk. The usual is middle click paste.

Comment: There are multiple clipboards.  Normally Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V uses a separate clipboard from select/middle click.  What app doesn't that work in?

Comment: @Mikel, It's works. My issue is that upon selecting the text to highlight, it becomes copied to the clipboard at the current position, resulting in the text I intend to paste being pushed down (or up) and the text I selected being copied instead.

Comment: Yes, understood. That's exactly what happens if you have the "Sync selections" option enabled in Clipman.  Try turning it off, or disabling your clipboard manager(s).

Comment: I have been having the _opposite_ problem where **I want it to copy on select**, so enabling "Sync selections" helped me out--thanks!!!

Answer (score 12):

I can only reproduce this if I enable "Sync Selections" in Clipman.

Make sure "Sync selections" is unchecked and you should be fine.

[image: Clipman settings]

For more background on the multiple clipboards, see:

- [For historical reasons, there are two selections...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77566/3169)
- [...in the X Windows environment there are multiple clipboards...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82326/3169)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this did not work for me. Perhaps it is a clipboard conflict

Comment: Was "Sync selections" enabled?  What do you mean by "clipboard conflict"?  Do you have other clipboard managers running too?  Try turning them all off for a minute.

Comment: I apologize for such asking such a silly question without realizing that in my .xprofile I had the following line 


**autocutsel -selection PRIMARY -fork &**

Comment: Out of curiosity, what were you trying to achieve with that `autocutsel` command? Is there a tutorial you were following?

Comment: I fancied a friends Archlinux install, he provided me with various scripts and programs to check out. I skimmed through them, his explanation of autocutsel was such that it combined the console clipboard then window based clipboard, clearly I do not know what this means, but I assumed it would be a good thing to have. Due to the fact that I couldn't find a man page just copied it and left it be.

Comment: Strangely, in Clipman 1.6.2 I had to *enable* "Sync mouse selections" and "Ignore mouse selections" to ignore the primary selection (With "Sync mouse selections" disabled, it wouldn't ignore them).

Answer (score 10):

I think you might want to turn off "Sync Selections" in the Clipman options.

See the [Clipman Documentation](http://docs.xfce.org/panel-plugins/clipman/start), specifically the distinction between the ["primary" and "default" clipboards](http://docs.xfce.org/panel-plugins/clipman/start#anatomy_of_a_clipboard) and the [general settings section](http://docs.xfce.org/panel-plugins/clipman/start#general_settings)

Comment: I apologize for such asking such a silly question without realizing that in my .xprofile I had the following line 

**autocutsel -selection PRIMARY -fork &**
Removing this solved my problem. Lesson learned: Know what your doing before you run / auto start something

Answer (score 2):

First of all that *should* actually be possible out of the box. However, the traditional *nix way has always been to select and then use the middle mouse button (or both buttons at once if you didn't have a middle one) to click. This is, and I am being objective here, much easier, it only needs two actions: select + click as opposed to select + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> which is three (or 5 if you count keys). I suggest you try getting used to that, it took me a while to when I first switched to Linux 15 years ago but I can't live without it now.

Anyway, as I said, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> should work out of the box. Where exactly does it not work for you? The issue you describe with clipman is probably just confusion because of the [multiple clipboards](http://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html) that most Linux systems have.

Comment: Some of the various places it does not work are; Sublime Text, Eclipse, IntelliJ, Firefox, Libre Writer. I am going to investigate the possibility of my desktop starting another clipboard, along with .xprofile, and autostart

Comment: Upon investigation the issue resulted from me forgetting I had pasted the following line in my .xprofile


**autocutsel -selection PRIMARY -fork &**

Comment: The down side of this is when you want to copy something and then replace something else. When you select the thing you want to replace, it overwrites the clipboard.