# RedHat5 stop copy on select

Tags: x11, clipboard

At work do we use RHEL5, with Gnome 2.28.2, we are also required to do development work in RHEL5.
RHEL5 have this strange feature that it will replace the clipboard with anything i highlight. This is very unproductive for me and really slows me down when working.

How can i disable this "feature" in RHEL5, i am not able to update to a newer version of RedHat or Gnome.

Comment: This is standard behavior for most any version of Linux or Unix that runs X11; it's known as primary vs. clipboard selection. Ordinarily, you should be able to copy with Ctrl-c and paste with Ctrl-v as usual (shortcuts depending on specific application) and ignore the primary selection, which only pastes on middle-click.

Comment: Don't know about the primary vs clipboard. If there is a text i want to replace with my current clipboard, made with Ctrl+V, i select the text i want the replace and it will override my clipboard, so i am not able to replace it.

Comment: That sounds like a nonstandard behavior, but the means of fixing it will vary heavily based on the application you're using. Look into documentation for specific apps.

Comment: This is for all apps, such as terminal, IntelliJ or gedit

Comment: This answer has a good explanation about what the two X11 'clipboards' are:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/213840/how-to-toggle-or-turn-off-text-selection-being-sent-to-the-clipboard

Comment: I am dieing to get this strange "feature" to work in OS X ... I used it long enough that it is annoying to live without actually :) but it shouldn't be replacing the clipboard that is accessible by copy and paste. It has its own separate buffer....